# ExtJs 5 Sencha-Charts adding listener

Tags: extjs, listener, sencha-charts

Hi I am having a hard time to figure out what's wrong on sencha-chart is this a bug or just a syntax error. To start I have an application which uses the new sencha-charts of extjs 5.  After I  adjusted I came up with the ff codes which is working already problem is when I add listener to it, the listener event is not working. Please can anyone help me on this.:

```
items: [{
        cls: 'chartclass',
        xtype: 'chart',
        flex: 1,
        interactions: [{
        type: 'panzoom',
        zoomOnPanGesture: false,
        axes: {
            left: {
                maxZoom: 1
            }
        }
    }],
        bind: '{chartstore}',
        minHeight: 350,
        animation: true,
        style: 'background: #fff',
        insetPadding: '40px 40px 20px 30px',
        width: '100%',
        height: 500,
        insetPadding: 40,


       interactions: 'itemhighlight',

      axes: [{
        type: 'numeric',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['utilcost'],
        fontSize: 12,
        grid: true,
        minimum: 0
    }, {
        type: 'category',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['date'],
        label: {
                rotate: {
                    degrees: -90
                }
            }
    }],
     //series
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',        
        xField: ['date'],
        yField: ['utilcost'],
        style: {
                 minGapWidth: 15,
                opacity: 0.80
        },
        highlight: {
                strokeStyle: 'black',
                fillStyle: '#c1e30d',
                lineDash: [5, 3]
        },
         tooltip: {
                trackMouse: true,
                style: 'background: #fff',
                renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                    var title = item.series.getTitle();
                    this.setHtml(storeItem.get(item.series.getYField()));
                }
            },

         label: {
                field: 'utilcost',
                display: 'insideEnd'
            },
        listeners:{  

                    itemmouseup: function(item){
                    alert('working');
                    }


        }


    }];
```

No error on the console log. all elements are working except firing the event.Please please help. I've tried a lots of solution already but none of those work.
Thank you

Comment: According to http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/application_architecture/view_controllers.html the default scope of listeners is the view controller. See if you have one and if that is not receiving events. I'd personally expect that if you use inline function as the handler then it should work as expected, yet its worth to try the view controller. Also you can try different events: itemclick, ...

Comment: Thanks for the response @saki, I've almost tried all the events none of it worked. Actually I was thinking that way too though will let you know if it works.

Comment: Hi starTreyk, Do you find out any solution for this ?? I am also facing same issue.. If you have solution please post..

Comment: Hi Amit, No still haven't find a solution for this. I think this does not included on this sencha-chart version. Try it on 5.1 version if it's working. Thanks